# "order by date" with string type

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

My question would look dumb but i haven't find any solution that works.
I have in my DB `DateTime` in the format `d/m/Y H:i:s` (day/month/year hour:min:sec) which is a **String**.

I need to order by `DateTime` a table but obviously it orders it by the day
`08/06/2015 11:25:37` is before `14/05/2015 10:18:20`.
I tried to convert `DateTime` into a date but it does not work.

Is there a way to convert it properly or to order it by years then month then day then hours etc. ?

Comment: Too bad it is a string type. Why??

Comment: Because I do a lot of things with this String. It has to be a string in my DB

Comment: Can you change the format to `Y/m/d H:i:s` ? That would sort correctly.

Comment: You have to use `str_to_date` to convert the string to date and than you can use it in `order by`

Comment: @Ch33f I know but I'm not english so I don't use date this way, we use them as day, month then year

@Jens `Fatal error: Call to undefined function str_to_date()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can order by converted value:

```
select * from TableName
order by STR_TO_DATE(ColumnName, 'd%/m%/Y% H%:i%:s%')
```

Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f5003/1

Answer (score 3):

You have to use str_to_date to convert the string to date and than you can use it in order by:

```
SELECT * from `table` order by STR_TO_DATE(column_name,'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s');
```

For more information, see the [mysql documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

You should think about changing the type of your column to a datetime type.